# discord.py - count the server create day

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a simple bot that counts the server create days and maybe some wired anniversary.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel(ID)

    for i in range(1):
        a=0
        a+=1
        await channel.send("server create " + str(a) + "day")
```

After running this code, the bot will auto-send below:

```
server create 1day
server create 1day
```

**How can I modify and let the results output change every 24 hours?**

My expected results are:

```
server create 1day
server create 2day
server create 3day
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get any date (e.g birthday) you can hardcode it and then calculate the difference. You can use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module:

```py
your_date = datetime.date(2021, 10, 20) # example creation date (year, month, day)
today = datetime.date.today() # today's date
delta = (today - your_date).days # I used ".days" to get only number of days
print(delta)
```

Output *(today - 20.11.2021)*:

```
31
```

But if you want to get the server creation date (as pointed by [@Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70046744/14048071)) you can also use [`created_at`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Guild.created_at) to get the server creation date.

```py
server = client.get_guild(ID) # get your server
creation_date = server.created_at # get creation date
today = datetime.date.today() # today's date
delta = (today - creation_date).days # I used ".days" to get only number of days
print(delta)
```

You can then loop it as you did in your example with the above code.

Comment: thanks for answer my question :D
but if i want to count like "He has been to UK __ days" and let the bot auto push out the message. Add it up one day at a time.
Can this also be done?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to achieve, but if you loop this code it will update - the number will increase every day. So, if you loop this code, tomorrow you will get `32` as output.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of **RiveN** is correct. However, I will provide a different solution too.

The way you are getting the channel is correct. To get the exact same difference in days, hours, minutes or seconds you can create your own function.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
import asyncio
import datetime
from discord.ext import tasks


def convert_timedelta(duration): # Function to convert the time
    days, seconds = duration.days, duration.seconds
    hours = seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = (seconds % 60)
    return days, hours, minutes, seconds

@tasks.loop(seconds=10) # Our tasks.loop
async def serverage():
    await asyncio.sleep(2) # Otherwise we will get a NoneType error
    server = client.get_guild(YourID)
    channel = client.get_channel(ChannelID)

    a = server.created_at # Server creation date

    b = datetime.datetime.utcnow() # UTC time, can be changed

    result = b - a # Do some maths
    days, hours, minutes, seconds = convert_timedelta(result) # Build in a converter

    await channel.send(f"The server is {days}d, {hours}h, {minutes}m, {seconds}s old.")

serverage.start() # We start our loop
client.run(TOKEN) # We run the bot
```

In this example, a message is sent every `10` seconds into your desired channel.

**Output:**

[image]